# Why do I not need the each method for jQuery when dealing with this array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am very new to jQuery so I am sorry in advance for the ease of this question. I have a page with several text boxes. I am using the selector shown in the code below to get all of the text boxes on the page. I am assuming this selector returns an array of text boxes. I want to clear all of those text boxes. In order to do this I set its val to an empty string. However I thought I would need to use the each method because I am dealing with an array. It appears to work without the each method. Why is this? Does jQuery automatically know to apply the val to every element within the selected array?

```
$(":text").val("");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, jQuery automatically apply all your expression to all of the selected elements. Method `each` in jQuery used, when you need execute some custom function with all selected elements (not standart function). When you use standart functions, you don't need use `each` method.
However, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
$(":text").each(function() { $(this).val(""); });
```

But you realize, that this is not pretty sight.

Answer (score 0):

empty all textboxes;

```
$("input:text").val("");
```

Empty text boxes with certain class;

```
$("input:text.classname").val("");
```

clear text boxes with array;
assume that you have text box names text1, text2, text3, ....

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  $("#text" + i).val('');
}
```

also you can use many methords using filter and each functions as well.

```
$("input:text").filter(":visible").filter(function(){
  return this.value !== ""; // you can return with any value
}).each(function(){
  something get sum or anything;
});
```

even without filter you can use each